# How can I migrate this to Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I sincerely beg for your patience and understanding.

The below code works by providing a box and a button.

The box contains a url and the button simply says, Convert.

If you click the convert button, it opens the contents of the url and converts it to pdf.

This works great.

Unfortunately, they want it translated as web service so other apps can use it to perform similar task by providing 2 input params, url and document name.

I have looked at several examples of creating and consuming web services, while they seem fairly simple, the way this code is written makes it extemely difficult to translate.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using EO.Pdf;

public partial class HtmlToPdf : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a PdfDocument object and convert
        //the Url into the PdfDocument object
        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
        HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(txtUrl.Text, doc);

        //Setup HttpResponse headers
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ClearHeaders();
        response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        //Send the PdfDocument to the client
        doc.Save(response.OutputStream);

        Response.End();
    }
}
```

If you could be kind enough to assist, I am truly grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic form of a web service is to use an [HTTP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx):

```
public class HtmlToPdfHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string url = context.Request["url"];
        string documentName = context.Request["name"];

        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
        HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(url, doc);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        doc.Save(context.Response.OutputStream);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

and then: `http://example.com/HtmlToPdfHandler.ashx?url=someurl&name=some_doc_name`

For more advanced services you might take a look at [`WCF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) or the upcoming [`Web API`](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU!!!

May God Bless you; this has given me grief all day!

Just so I won't bug you anymore after this genersous assistance, do I still have to create a markup page with 2 boxes and button?

Lastly, if I need call this, using, say, classic asp, this is still possible right?

Everything I read so far points to this being possible.

Again, many thanks!

Comment: Can anyone please tell why I am having so much difficulty running the code by Darin above?

I get this: Failed to convert Url 'http://www.google.com,/web/HtmlToPdfHandler.ashx'

When I type this to the browser:
http://test.com/test/HtmlToPdfHandler.ashx?url=someurl&name=some_doc_name and it points to this line:

HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(url, doc);

Maybe, I am passing the params correctly?