# I am having Issues converting this code to web service

Tags: c#, web-services

I was fortunate to have @Darin Dimitrov help me convert asp.net to web service on this link:

[How can I migrate this to Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460585/how-can-i-migrate-this-to-web-service)

This time, I tried to convert the code below but having issues.

Here is the code I am trying to convert, followed by my conversion attempt.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using EO.Pdf;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

partial class ToDems : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private void  // ERROR: Handles clauses are not supported in C#
    Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
            string itemList = Request.QueryString("from");
            string[] items = Strings.Split(itemList, ",");

            //Create a PdfDocument object
            PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();

            string item = null;


            foreach ( item in items) {
                HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(url, doc);

            }

            //We present "Save As" dialog 
            doc.Save(Response.OutputStream);

        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have tried but confused about the list and loop.

```
public class ToDems : IHttpHandler 
{ 
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
    { 
        string itemList = context.Request.QueryString["from"]; 
        string items = context.Strings.Split(itemList, ","); 

        PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(); 

        string item = null;

        foreach ( item in items) 
        {
            HtmlToPdf.ConvertUrl(url, doc);
        }


        doc.Save(context.Response.OutputStream); 
    } 

    public bool IsReusable 
    { 
        get { return false; } 
    } 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks all right to me... ¿what is that you expect that is not happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you should be passing "item" in your call to ConvertUrl, not "url." I'm assuming each "item" is a Url you want to convert into a Pdf...also need to fix the split call

Here's the change I'm talking about:

```
String[]    items = itemList.Split(',');
```

Comment: I changed that but still issues with FOR loop. My sense I didn't convert it correctly.

Comment: I am getting this error: 'System.Web.HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Strings' and no extension method 'Strings' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) on this line: string items[] = context.Strings.Split(itemList, ",");

Comment: Replace "Context.Strings" with "String". Note, too, that Split returns a String array, so change the type of your variable to string[]

Comment: thanks but the changes didn't work.

Infact, more errors were chreated when I changed from context.Strings to just String. now these errors, "Error: The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(string[], System.StringSplitOptions)' has some invalid arguments", "Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'string[]'", "Error 3 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.StringSplitOptions'".

Comment: I have modified my answer to site the specific change.